# Linq orderby several words

Tags: c#, linq

How can i order this list if searchWords contains the same words 2 times ?

```
var resultList = from c in context.Category
    join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
    join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
    from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where q.CustomerId == customerId 
    && (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
    || searchWords.Any(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
    || searchWords.Any(w => q.Text.Contains(w)))
    select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Can i do an if statement like below

```
 && (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
    || searchWords.Any(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
    || searchWords.Any(w => q.Text.Contains(w))) if(true) order
 select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

My last change (it works but it dont works for sub categories)

```
  var resultList = from c in context.Category
      join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
      join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
      from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where q.CustomerId == customerId
      && (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w) || c.Text.Contains(w) || q.Text.Contains(w)))
   orderby
     (searchWords.All(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
      && searchWords.All(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
      || searchWords.All(w => q.Text.Contains(w)))
   descending 
      select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what your code does and what you want it to do? Figuring it out from a huge linq query is a lot more error-prone than reading a description of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: what do you mean saying `it dont works for sub categories`? can you add example data?

Comment: If i search for "sick" and "vacation" (in my ui) it shows my menu ordered by questions and head categories that the both words sick and vacations is. That is correct. But my menu has also subcategories. And the subcategories can be vacation and the question is sick for example, it will not order it. Just the head category and the question.

Comment: add sreenshot or real data to question. i don't know structure of your classes and don't understand

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show matching items on the top (or on the bottom), you can set order on your condition:

```
var resultList = from c in context.Category
    join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
    join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
    from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where q.CustomerId == customerId 
    orderby 
        (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
        || searchWords.Any(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
        || searchWords.Any(w => q.Text.Contains(w))) 
    descending
    select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Also, if you need to set order between matching item, you can add other sort expressions to order matching items:

```
var resultList = from c in context.Category
    join q in context.Question on c.CategoryId equals q.CategoryId
    join a in context.Answer on q.QuestionId equals a.QuestionId into QuestAnsw
    from a2 in QuestAnsw.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where q.CustomerId == customerId 
    orderby 
        (searchWords.Any(w => a2.Text.Contains(w))
        || searchWords.Any(w => c.Text.Contains(w))
        || searchWords.Any(w => q.Text.Contains(w))) 
    descending,
    a.Id ascending //<---additional sort expression
    select new { Category = c, Question = q };
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I edited my answer. I think, it became better

Comment: I want to order items on the top that have got 2 matches

Comment: @kalle so, it's my first example

Comment: @kalle did you try it? what the result?

Comment: I used your first example and it didnt worked for me (i had to do some customizations) becouse "a2" "c" and "q" if they matched searchwords 2 times then i need to order it. so i used && and ||. It works but not for all. Do you have some other solutions i will be really thankfull.

Comment: You can see my last edit in the bottom, that is the query i use. But it dont work for subcategories

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked. But an exact search dont work. How can i compare strings for uppercase or the exact string?